# How to insert page breaks to keep certain data ranges together?

Tags: excel, excel-2016, page-break, vba

I'm trying to create a monthly report for my company and I'm having troubles with the aesthetics of it.  I have tables (with lots more data) that looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE8lN.png)

textwise looks like this (if picture is unavailable)

Customer 1 - 2018-###-#33

Customer 2 - 2017-###-###

----------------2018-###-###

Customer 3- 2018-###-###
etc

but sometimes there is a page break in the middle of a customer data, so that the title shows up on the first page but the last row(s) are on a new page.

I am trying to come up with a code to sense whether or not the data range will be split up, but I can not. I had thought maybe the pagebreak could be anticipated with the row number (as that's how I'm grouping the data) but one sheet has the break on row 101 (because this data starts at row 46) and the other has the pagebreak on row 106.

I have tried doing something similar to this:

```
If i >= 102 And start.row <= 101 Then
Worksheets(storenumber).HPageBreaks.Add before:=Rows(start.row)
Else
If i >= 176 And start.row <= 166 Then
Worksheets(storenumber).HPageBreaks.Add before:=Rows(start.row)
End If
End If
```

(with varying i = numbers and combination) but I haven't had any success.

Does anyone else have any other ideas? there normally is only one page break per storenumber sheet, with the except of one sheet.  (and some sheets don't need a page break as they only have say 5 customers)

I'm looking for an easier code (excel beginner/intermediate) but I'm open to any ideas.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you storing on "i"?

Comment: Your image shows Cust5 then blank then Cust5 again. But the others only have CustX on the first line, then blanks. Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BreakPagesCleanly()
Dim pb As HPageBreak
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
For Each pb In ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
    If pb.Location.Value = "" Then
        'go back to the last value
        Set rng = pb.Location.End(xlUp)
        ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add before:=rng
        DoEvents 'Seems to be required to give Excel time to catch up
    End If
Next pb

End Sub
```

Here's the before view, vs the after:

[image] [image]

Comment: @Morg Was this the kind of thing you were after?